# linsolve in SymPy: result does not depend on variable

Tags: python, sympy, linear-algebra

The following code returns the empty set as a result:

```
from sympy import *
a, x, y, z = symbols("a x y z")
linsolve([x-3, x-z-2, 2*x-2*z-a], [x,y,z])
```

However, for `a=4` there *are* solutions.  Is there a way to get an answer from SymPy that depends on the value of `a`?

Comment: See here: https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/16861

Answer (score 2):

Since `a` is a parameter of the system rather than an unknown `linsolve` will return the solution that is valid in the "generic" case. Since for almost all possible values of `a` there are no solutions you get the empty set. If you include `a` as an unknown then `linsolve` will find its value and also the set of solutions for the other variables:

```
In [8]: linsolve([x-3, x-z-2, 2*x-2*z-a], [x,y,z,a])
Out[8]: {(3, y, 1, 4)}
```